# Quality Mono/ASP.NET Dev environment on Windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

What is the best setup for developing ASP.NET/C# apps on Windows with the Mono runtime rather than VS and the MS runtime?

Ideally, I'd like to have the full mojo - autocomplete, debugger, Unit Tests and Apache/mod_mono or some other web server equivalent...

Answer (score 4):

Check out [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). This is the closest you can get to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [mono website](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) ?

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid there is nothing like Visual Studio for mono for windows, there is Monodevelop for Linux but that is far from running on windows any soon, however, if you just want to use the mono runtime to execute your application I see no inconvenience in developing inside Visual Studio and target the mono runtime.

There is a guide [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Working_with_Mono_and_Visual_Studio) in how to setup the Visual Studio environment to properly work with the mono runtime though im not sure if that guide is updated since it mentions a convertion tool from MSBuild to Make but I've heard that the last version of Monodevelop in Linux was capable of opening Visual Studio project files so maybe its even easier now.

You could  use SharpDevelop as EricSchaefer says but it does not have a Web Application designer tool like Visual Studio does so, if that is a must for you then Im afraid only Visual Studio will be a solution for you.

Let us know what you did :)

Comment: Update: MonoDeveloper runs fine on Windows today.

Comment: Indeed, long time since this comment, MD happily runs on windows and osx nowadays :)

Answer (score 0):

** Edit: Didn't spot the 'windows' bit first time round. MonoDevelop will run in windows, no installer tho. Also [mod_mono on windows](http://anmar.eu.org/mono/mod_mono/).

[OpenSuse](http://software.opensuse.org/) (OS), [mono repos](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) (Mono 2.2), [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) (ide with autocomplete + debugger). No debugger for ASP.NET tho, it'll come soon enough). Log4Net isn't a bad alternative meanwhile. Unit tesing... NUnit and (maybe something like) [windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/)